# Complexity of downsizing STL vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl, time-complexity, stdvector

What is the time complexity of downsizing (reducing the size) an `std::vector<int>`?
I get that it does not reallocate memory. On custom classes, it may need
to call destructors for all elements that are removed. But with integers,
will the downsizing happen in constant time?

Comment: Fundamental types don't have destructors, but `vector` is likely to use `placement-new` internally and may still call destructors on them, which is allowed.  The compiler may be smart enough to realize the destructor calls are no-ops and optimize them out, or the `vector` implementation may be specialized to realize it and just skip them, either way causing the resize to effectively be O(1) since the only operation would be just to decrement the `size()` value. This really depends on the `vector``s *implementation*, I don't think the time complexity for different types is outlined.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you mean by "reducing the size" of a vector.

Usually, people remove elements from a vector by calling `erase`.  If you erase stuff *at the end* of the vector, then things are simple, and all that happens is that the elements are destructed - which, as Remy pointed out, is a no-op for `int`s.

If you're erasing from somewhere other than the end, then elements have to be shuffled around, and that takes time. Fortunately for your use case, copying an `int` is cheap, but it's not zero. So there's no way that removing an element from the beginning/middle of a vector can be constant time.

Note: calling `resize` on a vector to make it smaller removes elements at the end.

Comment: Does any library (of which you're aware) include specializations to avoid calling the pseudo-dtor for simple types like `int`?

Comment: Do you have evidence (say, godbolt) of a library calling such a psuedo-dtor?

Comment: @JerryCoffin Even my tutorials on vectors explain how to do that optimizations. I would expect professional things to do it.  https://lokiastari.com/blog/2016/03/19/vector-simple-optimizations/index.html

Comment: @MarshallClow - yes, I would be using resize() to reduce the size.

Comment: Sorry, I had to do some work for a while there. My answer to Marshall is that no, I haven't tested, so I'm not sure. @MartinYork: thinking  more about it, I suspect it's unnecessary. A loop that invokes dtors for a type in which the dtor is a nop should probably be eliminated as dead code (but see above--I haven't tested to be sure).